# The regx in pygrep always returns True

Tags: python, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I'm using the pygrep in `pre-commit` and here is my settings:

```
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: jira-ticket
        name: check for jira ticket
        entry: '(ERP-[0-9]+ #(feat|fix|docs|style|refactor|perf|test|chore) .+)'
        args: [--multiline]
        language: pygrep
        stages: [commit-msg]
```

I want to check the commit message format but no mater what I entered, it always returns true.

```
$ git commit -m "why"
[WARNING] Unstaged files detected.
[INFO] Stashing unstaged files to C:\Users\oliver.chiu\.cache\pre-commit\patch1657183664-20160.
[INFO] Restored changes from C:\Users\oliver.chiu\.cache\pre-commit\patch1657183664-20160.
[WARNING] Unstaged files detected.
[INFO] Stashing unstaged files to C:\Users\oliver.chiu\.cache\pre-commit\patch1657183666-11436.
check for jira ticket....................................................Passed
[INFO] Restored changes from C:\Users\oliver.chiu\.cache\pre-commit\patch1657183666-11436.
[purchase_merge_ui dc8bafc9] why
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you also commented on github!  pick one in the future not both!

your regex doesn't follow [the pattern I outlined in that issue you commented on](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks/issues/460#issuecomment-593752871) -- here is the example I used:

```yaml
repos:
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: jira-ticket
        name: check for jira ticket
        language: pygrep
        entry: '\A(?![A-Z]+-[0-9]+)'
        args: [--multiline]
        stages: [commit-msg]
```

note that we're using a **negative lookahead** -- by default `pygrep` is used to find *problems* with things and you're trying to do the opposite

right now your current pattern will only *fail* on correctly named things rather than only *allow* correctly named things

adapting your pattern to the one I outlined in the issue you'd want something like:

```yaml
            entry: '\A(?!ERP-[0-9]+ #(feat|fix|docs|style|refactor|perf|test|chore) .+)'
```

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit